# Rails 4: How i can get record of has_many through relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 3 tables: Phonecalls, Results, Questions.I have 3 models also : Phonecall, Result, Question

Schema of  Phonecalls is:
id, date,user_id

Schema of Questions is:
id, text,error

Schema of Results is:
id, phonecall_id, question_id, result

My Phonecall.rb is:

```
class Phonecall < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :results
  has_many :questions, :through => :results
end
```

My Result.rb is:

```
class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :question
  belongs_to :phonecall
end
```

And my Question.rb:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :result
  has_many :phonecalls, :through => :result
end
```

So how i can get Question properties in this loop:

```
<%
@phonecalls.each do |ph|
  ph.results.each do |r|

%>
    <%= ph.id %>
    <%= r.id %>       
<%
  end
end
%>
```

If i try to get r.question.id - i have error. If i try to do some loop with ph.questions - i have error.

How i can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, my problem was in my relationships.

in Result.rb i told that **result belogs to question** but it's false.
Now i have this relatioships:
Result.rb:

```
class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :phonecall
end
```

Questio.rb

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :result
  has_many :phonecalls, :through => :result
end
```

It's work for me.

Answer (score 1):

`has_many :phonecalls, through: :result` allows you to do:

`question.phonecalls`  that will give you back an array of `phonecalls` associated with your one `question` instance.

Inversely and to answer your question it would be:

```
@phonecalls.each do |ph|
  ph.questions.each do |question|
   puts ph.id
   puts question.id
  end
end
```

Comment: `each` is fine here - your issue was that you were calling the join table `results` and not what you actually wanted the `questions`.  glad that worked for you!

Comment: i'am sorry, but it's doesn't work. I forgot to save my file. Now i have : Mysql::Error: Unknown column 'questions.result_id' in 'on clause': SELECT `questions`.* FROM `questions` INNER JOIN `results` ON `questions`.`result_id` = `results`.`id` WHERE `results`.`phonecall_id` = ?

Comment: So i can say, that reale table questions has no result_id field

Comment: For me it's problem with relations

Comment: also for me problem is here: has_many :questions, :through => :results